# Permutation of reduced words

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to understand Page 217 of the book Abstract Algebra by Summit and Foote.

$\sigma_s$ Is a left-multiplication by an element s. This gives a permutation.

I consider for example $S=(a,b)$.

Thìs Is the set of letters a and b.

So $F(S)$ Is the free group.

Now consider a Word $w=aaabba$ for example.

let be $s=b\cdot ba^{-1}$.

Applying $\sigma_s$, $w$ becomes $bbaabba$?

Is that the permutation?

So by applying $\sigma$ to all words in $F(S)$, this generates the permutation of all words in F(S)?

Comment: What is $a^{-1}$ in this context?  was $F(S)$ meant to denote the free group on $a,b$?  That's not the same as what you wrote.

Comment: @lulu yes the free group

Comment: Ah, that's not what you wrote.  I suggest editing for clarity.  In any case, yes. $bba^{-1}aaabba=bbaabba$.

Comment: @lulu ok and Is that the permutation?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that.  It's the action, by left multiplication, by one given group element on another.

Comment: @lulu ok but this induces a permutation of all the words?

Comment: Left multiplication by a fixed group element always gives a permutation of the group.

Comment: Permutation Means that every Word in F(S) Maps to a different Word?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141262/discussion-between-pirofotulis-and-lulu).

Comment: No need for a chat.  A permutation on a set is the same as a bijection so, yes, every element must go to an element and that process must hit every element exactly once. For finite sets, this just means rearranging the list.  Of course, it's harder to have intuition for permutations of infinite sets.

Comment: For instance, $n\mapsto n+1$ is a permutation of the integers.  $n\mapsto 2n$ is not a permutation of the integers since nothing goes to $1$.  It is, however, a permutation of the rationals.

Comment: @lulu ok thanks